# Removing KDE-BootLogo during boot in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: kde, 19.10, plasma

I have an issue. I recently installed KDE plasma in my ubuntu eaon.

After using for a while I felt a lag in the UI and the boot time was thrice as much as that of the normal time. So I decided to go back to gnome.

I removed kde and its trace, but the kplasma logo is still there during booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove [Plymouth theme for Kubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=plymouth-theme-kubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text
```

and then reboot.